# Get create Custom Block in FrontEnd Product page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, product

In my magento i want to create a Block in Product Page for this itried like this

[Magento- How can i add a new custom block in product details page using module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575391/magento-how-can-i-add-a-new-custom-block-in-product-details-page-using-module)

But no use

Any thing wrong i did here

Any Ideas

Answer (score 0):

Hello check below code may be help you

1. add into product template **(view.phtml)** where you want

   ```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mynewblock');?>
   ```
2. call block into your custom **template xml or catalog.xml**

   ```
    <catalog_product_view>
          <reference name="product.info">   
               <block type="core/template" name="mynewblock" template="hello/hello.phtml" />
          </reference>  
    </catalog_product_view>
   ```